# Get the average value between a specified set of rows

Tags: visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

Everyone, I'm building a report using **Visual Studio 2012**

I want to be able to **average a group of values** between a specific set of rows.

What I have so far is something like this.

```
=(Count(Fields!SomeField.Value))*.1
```

and

```
=(Count(Fields!SomeField.Value))*.9
```

I want to use those two values to get the **Average** of `Fields!SomeField.Value` between those to numbers of the row. Basically I'm removing the top and bottom 10% of the data and get the middle 80% to average out. Maybe there is a better way to do this? Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle it in SQL itself.
**Method 1:** 
Use `NTILE` function. Go through this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175126.aspx) to learn more about `NTILE`.

Try something like this

```
WITH someCTE AS (
 SELECT SomeField, NTILE(10) OVER (ORDER BY SomeField) as percentile
 FROM someTable)

SELECT AVG(SomeField) as myAverage 
FROM someCTE WHERE percentile BETWEEN 2 and 9
```

if your dataset is bigger

```
WITH someCTE AS (
 SELECT SomeField, NTILE(100) OVER (ORDER BY SomeField) as percentile
 FROM someTable)

SELECT AVG(SomeField) as myAverage 
FROM someCTE WHERE percentile BETWEEN 20 and 90
```

**METHOD 2:**

```
SELECT Avg(SomeField) myAvg
From someTable
Where SomeField NOT IN
(
SELECT Top 10 percent someField From someTable order by someField ASC
UNION ALL
SELECT Top 10 percent someField From someTable order by someField DESC
)
```

**Note:** 
Test for boundary conditions to make sure you are getiing what you need. If needed tweak above sql code.

For NTILE: Make sure you NTILE parameter is less(or equal) than the number of rows in the table.